# Incorrect URL/XPath when using Google sheets IMPORTXML

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import a search result from google to my spreadsheet. I've had success with Wikipedia pages, but for some reason, Google search isn't working correctly (giving a "could not fetch url" error). I'm sure the problem is somewhere in my URL or XPath, but I've been trying a variety of things and I'm lost. Here is what I've got:

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q=dom+fera+easy+thing+released", "//div[@class='Z0LcW XcVN5d']")`

I'm linking the spreadsheet below as view-only for reference as well. Ultimately the goal is to be able to webscrape release years of songs. I'd appreciate any help!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bt8MJ23nfGAv6ianaR-sd7DM5DNn98p7zWSG1UzBlEY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't parse results from GoogleSearch in Google Sheets.
Using Discogs, MusicBrainz, All Music... to get the release dates could be useful.
But it seems some of your groups are little known. So, you can use Youtube to fetch the dates.

Note : we assume the year of publication on Youtube corresponds to the year of release.
Of course, that's not 100% true. For example, artists can clip their video months after release. Or publish nothing on Youtube.
So this method will work with a wide range of songs but not ALL the songs. With recent bands and songs, it should be OK.

To do this you can use the `Youtube API` or `IMPORTXML` formulas. In both cases, we always take the first result (relevant order) of the search engine as source.

[image: Results]

You need an [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=fr) and an [ImportJSON script](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/ae64c908b82cc8cf8840e176930ad937883fbe37/ImportJSON.gs) (credits to Brad Jasper) to use the API method. Once you have installed the script and activated your API key,you can paste in cell B3:

```
="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={yourAPIKey}&part=snippet&type=video&filter=items&regionCode=FR&q="&ENCODEURL(A3)
```

We generate the url to query with the content you input in column A.
We use "regionCode=FR" since some songs are not available in the US ("i need you FMLYBND"). That way we get the correct release date.

In C3, you can paste :

```
=LEFT(QUERY(ImportJSON(B3);"SELECT Col11 LIMIT 1 label Col11''";1);4)
```

We parse the JSON, select the column of interest, the line of interest, then we clean the result.

With the `IMPORTXML` method, you can paste in E3 :

```
="https://www.youtube.com"&IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="&A3;"(//div[@class='yt-lockup-thumbnail contains-addto'])[3]/a/@href")
```

We construct the url with the first search result of the search engine.

In F3, you can paste :

```
=LEFT(IMPORTXML(E3;"//meta[@itemprop='datePublished']/@content");4)
```

We parse the previously built url, then we extract the year of publication.

As you can see, there's a difference in the results on line 5. That's because the song is not available in the US. The first result returned in the `IMPORTXML` method is different from the one of the `API` method which uses a "FR" flag.

Side note : I'm based in Europe. So ";" in the formulas should be replaced with ",".

Answer (score 0):

google does not support web scraping of google search into google sheets. this option was disabled 2 years ago. you will need to use alternative search engine